# MVC Set Selected Value of @Html.DropDownListFor to Querystring value

Tags: model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor, querystringparameter

I think I'm almost there, but for some reason the dropdown is defaulting to the first item in the list instead of the value that I'm passing (defaultChoice). Any ideas?

```
@{
    var defaultChoice = Request.QueryString["id"];
    var choices = new SelectList(ViewBag.Choices, "myItemId", "myProductName", defaultChoice);
}


@Html.DropdownListFor(m =>m.myItemIdPrimary, choices)
```

**Final Code BUT it generates and error:**

```
string defaultChoice = Request.QueryString["id"];
int idVal = int.Parse(defaultChoice);
var choices = new SelectList(ViewBag.Choices, "myItemId", "myProductName", idVal);

Model.myItemIdPrimary = idVal;
```

**I get the Error:** Value cannot be null (on the int idVal = int.Parse(defualtChoice) line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign value to model.

Like this

```
@{
    var defaultChoice = Request.QueryString["id"];
    var choices = new SelectList(ViewBag.Choices, "myItemId", "myProductName", defaultChoice);
   Model.myItemIdPrimary=defaultChoice;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You rock! I have another question but I will create another post.